# How to loop through 2 arrays to create a new key/value object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I've got 2 arrays - countryNames and countryCodes. The index sequence of items inside those arrays align as they come from the same API, i.e. countryNames[0] is Afghanistan and countryCodes[0] is "AF" etc.

I am trying to create a new, seperate object to store the data in key/value pairs neatly (like JSON object does) but I had no success yet. Somebody suggested to loop through them but I'm not too sure how to do that. Any help would be much appreciated!

Below is the only code that I had some kind of success with. It gives me an object (albeit weird looking one) but it doesn't store the data in key / value pair relationship.

```
 var keys = [];
 var values = [];


 fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
.then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
.then((data) => {
    const codes = data.map(item => item.alpha2Code);
    values.push(codes);

    const names = data.map(item => item.name);
    keys.push(names);

    var result = [];
    keys.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = values[i]);
    console.log(result);
});
```

I just want to have something like -
 {
CountryName: CountryCode,
2ndCountryName: 2ndCountryCode,
3rdCounryName: 3rdCountryCode,
etc.....
};

Comment: could you please add the input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a JavaScript Object from two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127989/creating-a-javascript-object-from-two-arrays)

Comment: I am aware of the similar question being asked and I have tried every solution proposed there - nothing worked for me, and I am unsure why. I have managed to make it work with the code below that I marked to be the most helpful. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.reduce to the rescue:

```js
fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
      const result = data.reduce((countries, item)=> {
       countries[item.name] = item.alpha2Code;
        return countries;
      }, {});
      console.log(result);
  });
```

if you want to learn more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

```js
fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then((response) => {
 return response.json();
}).then((data) => {
 var result = {}
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  result[data[i].name] = data[i].alpha2Code;
 }
 console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
.then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
.then((data) => {
  const results = data.reduce((agg, item) => {
    agg[item.name] = item.alpha2Code
    return agg
  }, {})
  console.log(results)
})
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the questions. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var keys = [];
 var values = [];


 fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
.then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
.then((data) => {
    const codes = data.map(item => item.alpha2Code);
    values.push(codes);

    const names = data.map(item => item.name);
    keys.push(names);

    var result = [];
    
    keys[0].forEach((key, i) => {
       const obj = {};
       obj[values[0][i]] = key;       
       result.push(obj);
     }
    );
    
    console.log(result);
});
```