# How to do one to one mapping of two arrays in karate

Tags: karate

```
* def alphabets = ["a","b","c"]
* def number = ["1","2","3"]
```

So that the final mapped result should be

```
final =[{"a":"1"},{"b":2""},{"c":"3"}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a JavaScript Object from two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127989/creating-a-javascript-object-from-two-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Next time maybe you shouldn't tag your question as JS / JSON ;)

```
* def fun = function(x, i){ var pair = {}; pair[x] = number[i]; return pair }
* def pairs = karate.map(alphabets, fun)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this Array `reduce` function. It should give the expected result.

```
alphabets.reduce((mem, alphabet, index) => {
  mem.push({[alphabet]: number[index]});
  return mem;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var alphabets = ["a","b","c"]
var number = ["1","2","3"]
res=alphabets.map((e,i)=>({[e]:number[i]}))
console.log(res)
```