# JavaScript: Restructure and array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I get my data from an API which looks like this:

```
  desserts: [
    {
      name: ["Frozen Yohurt", "Ice cream Sandwich", "Egg"],
      calories: [159, 237, 109]
    },
```

My component (Vuetify Datatable) expects the data in a quite different form, like this:

```
    desserts: [
    { name: "Frozen Yogurt", calories: 159},        
    { name: "Ice cream sandwich", calories: 237 },
     {name: "Egg", calories: 109 }
    ],
```

I was not able to solve it. This ([Creating a JavaScript Object from two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127989/creating-a-javascript-object-from-two-arrays)) looks quite similar, but gives a different result. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That link already has the answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the index parameter in [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) can be used so it works for any number of objects in the array.

```js
let arr = [
    {
      name: ["Frozen Yohurt", "Ice cream Sandwich", "Egg"],
      calories: [159, 237, 109]
    }
];
let res = arr.flatMap(({name,calories}) => 
  name.map((name,idx)=>({name,calories:calories[idx]})));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @DataMastery No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this in one iteration per object. Just make sure the two arrays have equal lengths:

```js
let desserts = [
    {
      name: ["Frozen Yohurt", "Ice cream Sandwich", "Egg"],
      calories: [159, 237, 109]
    }
];

let list = [];
for(let i = 0; i < desserts.length; i++){
     let obj = desserts[i];
     if(obj.name.length == obj.calories.length){
          for(let i = 0; i < obj.name.length; i++){
               list.push({name: obj.name[i], calories: obj.calories[i]});
          }
     }
}
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the object's entries and map the found values along with the key as objects.

This approach takes only the first object found in  the `desserts` array.

```js
const
    desserts = { name: ["Frozen Yohurt", "Ice cream Sandwich", "Egg"], calories: [159, 237, 109] },
    result = Object
        .entries(desserts)
        .reduce((r, [k, values]) => values.map((v, i) => ({ ...r[i], [k]: v })), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to flatten each item to your desired structure

```js
const obj = {
  desserts: [{
    name: ["Frozen Yohurt", "Ice cream Sandwich", "Egg"],
    calories: [159, 237, 109]
  }]
};

const result = obj.desserts.reduce((acc, { name, calories }) => {
  Array.prototype.push.apply(acc, name.map((item, idx) => ({
    name: item,
    calories: calories[idx]
  })));
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

To convert the data into what you want is like this:

```js
const requiredOutput = [];
 
for(let instance of desserts){
  instance.name.forEach((name, index)=>{
    requiredOutput.push({
        name: name,
        calories: instance.calories[index]
    })
  })
}
```