# How can I form an object with 2 array efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
const x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

I'm trying to combine the two array into an array of objects such that it becomes:

```
[{x: 0, y: 6}, {x: 1, y: 7}, {x: 2, y: 8}, {x: 3, y: 9}, {x: 4, y: 10}, {x: 5, y: 11}]
```

Currently what I did was to loop the length of one of the arrays then push the object to the new array.

```
let newArray = []
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   newArray.push({x: x[i], y: y[i]})
}
```

Just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, thanks!

Comment: Use `map`: `x.map((x,i)=>({x, y:y[i]}))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a JavaScript Object from two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127989/creating-a-javascript-object-from-two-arrays)

Comment: Maybe use loadsh [`zipWith`](https://lodash.com/docs#zipWith) ?

Comment: From complexity perspective - no. `O(n)` is the best you can do, since you still need to iterate through the arrays. In terms of execution speed - not very likely. See [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). The main problem is that there is no *generic* answer to this question, it depends on your use case, your data and more. But also, many times the difference doesn't actually matter. Shaving off, say, 1ms is not going to make your application extremely faster if this code is not a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is good. Another way using `.map`:

```js
const getCoordinates = (xCoordinates=[], yCoordinates=[]) =>
   xCoordinates.map((x,index) => ({x, y:yCoordinates[index]}));

console.log( getCoordinates([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]) );
```

Another way using `for-loop` (to handle different list sizes):

```js
const getCoordinates = (xCoordinates=[], yCoordinates=[]) => {
  const coordinates = [];
  for(let i = 0, j = 0; i < xCoordinates.length && j < yCoordinates.length; i++, j++)
    coordinates.push({x:xCoordinates[i], y:yCoordinates[i]});
  return coordinates;
}

console.log( getCoordinates([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to do the same thing.

```js
const x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

const newArray = x.map((number, index) => ({x: number, y: y[index]}));

console.log(newArray)
```

And here is the same thing using 'reducer'

```js
const x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]


const newArray = x.reduce((arr, n, index) => {
  arr.push({x: n, y: y[index]});
  return arr;
}, [])

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Is this "more efficient"?

Comment: Nope, simple loop is always faster as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

You could go over an object and get the entries for having an array of objects.

This approach works as well for more arrays.

```js
const
    x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    result = Object
        .entries({ x, y })
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => ({ ... r[i], [k]: v })), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```