# How to merge two arrays to an object?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays with the same length.

```
array1 = ['title', 'details', 'price', 'discount'];
array2 = ['product name', 'product details', 200, 20];
```

Want to convert them into one object like following

```
newObject = {
  title: 'product name',
  details: 'product details',
  price: 200,
  discount: 20
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a JavaScript Object from two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127989/creating-a-javascript-object-from-two-arrays)

Comment: `newObject = array1.reduce((acc,arr1,i) => (acc[arr1] = array2[i],acc),{})`

Comment: tried map and forEach but couldn't. :(

Answer (score 5):

You can create the pairs using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and convert the result into the object using [`Object#fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const 
  array1 = ['title', 'details', 'price', 'discount'],
  array2 = ['product name', 'product details', 200, 20];

const newObject = Object.fromEntries(
  array1.map((e,i) => ([e, array2[i]]))
);

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: `newObject = array1.reduce((acc,arr1,i) => (acc[arr1] = array2[i],acc),{})` is perhaps more elegant

Comment: @mplungjan I chose this solution since it shows the collection of pairs and the transformation to the expected output object. Will update the answer with your approach as well, thanks for the comment!

Comment: Or just leave it as a comment