# Merge two arrays to multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I already have an object witch has two arrays:

```js
const services = {
        iconAndLink: [
            'Icon1',
            'Icon2',
            'Icon3',
        ],
        name: [
            'Name1',
            'Name2',
            'Name3',
        ],
    };
```

I looked into Object.assign(), array.reduce(), map etc... and can't seem to find a decent answer here that merges these two.

For final result I need:

```js
services = [
        {
            icon: 'Icon1',
            name: 'Name1'
        },
        {
            icon: 'Icon2',
            name: 'Name2'
        },
        {
            icon: 'Icon3',
            name: 'Name3'
        },
    ]
```

Note that I need to have the `icon` and `name` keys.

Is this even possible in js?

Comment: Yes it is possible. However, will the two arrays always be of the same length?

Comment: Does this thread help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127989/creating-a-javascript-object-from-two-arrays/39128136

Comment: @CroogQT See that there's a static key here. Just name and icon.

Comment: You can't use the same variable `services` for the source and result, since it's declared `const`.

Comment: Why couldn't you do it with `map()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```js
const services = {
  iconAndLink: ["Icon1", "Icon2", "Icon3"],
  name: ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"],
};

let result = services.iconAndLink.map(function (icon, index) {
  return { icon: services.iconAndLink[index], name: services.name[index] };
});


console.log(result);
```

Make sure both arrays same the same length and both are ordered

Comment: @Kinglish posted this with a forEach. What difference does this make with using map?

Comment: Both are simillar, but different. Map is more the functional way, and create a new array. forEach allows you to change the original array.

The map function will receive a function that will run on each item on array and create a new array with all created objects. 

You can read more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

For performance point, map is slight faster (as seen here: https://morioh.com/p/b2d058745cb8)

Answer (score 1):

A simple forEach loop using `index` would do the trick

```js
const services = {
  iconAndLink: [
    'Icon1',
    'Icon2',
    'Icon3',
  ],
  name: [
    'Name1',
    'Name2',
    'Name3',
  ],
};

let newarray = [];
services.iconAndLink.forEach((el, index) => newarray.push({
      icon: el,
      name: services.name[index]
    })
    );

    console.log(newarray)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const services={iconAndLink:["Icon1","Icon2","Icon3"],name:["Name1","Name2","Name3"]};
    
const res = services.name.map((e, i) => ({
  icon: e,
  name: services.iconAndLink[i]
}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the arrays are of the same size, you can do:

```js
const services = { iconAndLink: [ 'Icon1', 'Icon2', 'Icon3', ], name: [ 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', ], };
const newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < services.iconAndLink.length; i++) {
    newArr.push({icon: services.iconAndLink[i], name: services.name[i]})
}

console.log(newArr)
```