# How to merge two arrays to make an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

consider i have an array say
let arr1=["john","Bruce","Clent"];
and
let arr2=[55,33,22];

Then how can i make an object out of this in javascript
object should look like:{"john":55,"Bruce":33,"Clent":22};
it should take arr1 as object's keys and arr2 as object'values

Comment: See here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127989/creating-a-javascript-object-from-two-arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop the array, but use the index to match the key and value.

```
const arr1=["john","Bruce","Clent"];
const arr2=[55,33,22];

const obj = {};
arr1.forEach((val, i) => {
    obj[val] = arr2[i];
});
```