# How to create dynamic list items in Google forms from 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have this in a spreadsheet:

| REGION | SITE |
| --- | --- |
| R1 | S1 |
| R1 | S2 |
| R2 | S1 |
| R2 | S2 |
| R2 | S3 |
| R3 | S1 |
| R3 | S2 |
| R3 | S3 |

In a form, the user can pick a region and I want to generate a list item with only the sites related to the chosen region.

I tried with a map/object based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127989/create-an-object-from-an-array-of-keys-and-an-array-of-values)

but the result only keeps the first site for each region

```
{
 R1 : S1,
 R2 : S1,
 R3 : S1
}
```

What I want (at least I think it could help me to get a depending list validation):

```
{
 R1: [S1,S2],
 R2: [S1,S2,S3],
 R3: [S1,S2,S3],
}//",}" added by editor
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected value. Can you provide your expected value?

Comment: Dynamic options are not supported by Google Form. You should consider to create your own Form with [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your provided sample expected value, I believed your goal is as follows.

- From your showing table (Spreadsheet), you want to retrieve the following value using Google Apps Script.

  ```
    {
      "R1":["S1","S2"],
      "R2":["S1","S2","S3"],
      "R3":["S1","S2","S3"]
    }
  ```

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const res = values.reduce((o, [a, b]) => (o[a] = o[a] ? [...o[a], b] : [b], o), {});
  console.log(res)
}
```

- When this script is run, `res` is `{"R1":["S1","S2"],"R2":["S1","S2","S3"],"R3":["S1","S2","S3"]}`.

#### Testing:

From your showing table, `values` is `[["R1","S1"],["R1","S2"],["R2","S1"],["R2","S2"],["R2","S3"],["R3","S1"],["R3","S2"],["R3","S3"]]`. When this value is used, the test script is as follows.

```js
const values = [["R1","S1"],["R1","S2"],["R2","S1"],["R2","S2"],["R2","S3"],["R3","S1"],["R3","S2"],["R3","S3"]]
const res = values.reduce((o, [a, b]) => (o[a] = o[a] ? [...o[a], b] : [b], o), {});
console.log(res)
```

#### Note:

- In your expected value, you show as follows. But, I thought that from your showing table, `R2` of 2nd `R2: [S1,S2,S3]` might be `R3`.

  ```
    {
     R1: [S1,S2],
     R2: [S1,S2,S3],
     R2: [S1,S2,S3]
  ```

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: you thought well :) thank you

Comment: @mthgn Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.